# Lengths of a staircase and the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle with the adjacent of 1 unit and the perpendicular of 1 unit for each

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let we have a horizontal line segment of 1-unit length and at the left edge point of the line segment we have a perpendicular line segment of 1-unit length, i.e., both the line segments are perpendicular to each other. If we make a “staircase” of equal steps from the top of the perpendicular line segment to the right edge point of the horizontal line segment, we find the length of staircase is always 2 units, no matter how small steps we make (see also the photo attached).

But as soon as the staircase becomes a straight line, its length becomes $\sqrt{2}$ (the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle with adjacent and perpendicular of 1 unit each). I'm confused between the staircase of a large number of steps (steps being too small as if the staircase were a straight line) having length of 2 units and the a straight line there with length of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12907/766324

Comment: and you should type the question , it is not convenient for all users to see the question in the Image , in case you need help with math jax : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/766324

Comment: I discard such questiosn as they are too bothersome to read because of the hsnd writing and the glare.

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between [Taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) and [Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) - different [metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) give different values to distances, like 'as the crow flies' (a straight line) or 'by road'.